# A variable is excepted as a attribute python logging module

Tags: python

Hello Stack Overflow users,

i'm writing a simple code and i got a "AttributeError" exception

```
log_level = 'INFO' # DEBUG - INFO - WARNING - ERROR - CRITICAL

logging.basicConfig(
        format=('%(asctime)s > [%(levelname)s] in %(funcName)s on line '
                '%(lineno)d > %(message)s'), level = logging.log_level, \
                filename='logs.log', filemode='w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Sorry for asking a suck stupid question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `level = logging.log_level` should be just `log_level` maybe ? It will probably be easier to help you if you share the full error stack trace.

Comment: Thank you it worked :) !

Comment: My pleasure : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear on your requirement, but the below approach can be a neat solution

```
def get_logger(cls, logger_name, create_file=False):

    # create logger
    log = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    log.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)

    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    if create_file:
        # create file handler for logger.
        fh = logging.FileHandler('my_log.log')
        fh.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    # reate console handler for logger.
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add handlers to logger.
    if create_file:
        log.addHandler(fh)

    log.addHandler(ch)
    return log
```